# How to subtract row values in reference to the associated columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I would like to subtract consecutive values in rows in reference to their values in the other columns.

The data frame looks like this:

```
     A        B    
1   "Sat"     7  
2   "Sat"     9
3   "Sat"     5
4   "Sun"     8  
5   "Sun"     4
6   "Sun"     6
```

I would like to subtract consecutive values of the B column in reference to the A column and the output should be like this:

```
     A        B    
1   "Sat"     0  
2   "Sat"    +2
3   "Sat"    -4
4   "Sun"     0  
5   "Sun"    -4
6   "Sun"     2
```

I have been using `df.diff()` to get this done in the whole dataframe but here it is like (key, value) with key from A column and several values from the B column. I want to subtract values in B column as long as the key in A column is "Sat" and when it encounter the second key in A column which is "Sun" should restart subtraction.

Any help in solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if necessary [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `A`, then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), for replace `NaN` [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['B'] = df.sort_values('A').groupby('A')['B'].diff().fillna(0)
print (df)
     A    B
1  Sat  0.0
2  Sat  2.0
3  Sat -4.0
4  Sun  0.0
5  Sun -4.0
6  Sun  2.0
```

If need cast to `int`:

```
df['B'] = df.sort_values('A').groupby('A')['B'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
     A  B
1  Sat  0
2  Sat  2
3  Sat -4
4  Sun  0
5  Sun -4
6  Sun  2
```

Another solution with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), where add `0` if [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) is not equal with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column `A` by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df['B'] = df.B.diff().mask(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()), 0)
print (df)
     A    B
1  Sat  0.0
2  Sat  2.0
3  Sat -4.0
4  Sun  0.0
5  Sun -4.0
6  Sun  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming groups in column `'A'` are always together

```
a, b = df.A.values, df.B.values
np.append(0, np.where(a[:-1] == a[1:], np.diff(b), 0))

array([ 0,  2, -4,  0, -4,  2])
```

We can overwrite our column `'B'` with

```
a, b = df.A.values, df.B.values
df.assign(B=np.append(0, np.where(a[:-1] == a[1:], np.diff(b), 0)))

     A  B
1  Sat  0
2  Sat  2
3  Sat -4
4  Sun  0
5  Sun -4
6  Sun  2
```

Or we can stick to strictly `pandas`

```
df.assign(B=df.B.diff().where(df.A == df.A.shift(), 0).astype(int))

     A  B
1  Sat  0
2  Sat  2
3  Sat -4
4  Sun  0
5  Sun -4
6  Sun  2
```

***timing***
*small data*
[image]

*larger data*
[image]